# Error with MDX the divide function expects a string or numeric

Tags: mdx

I have the expression in MDX

```
IIF
(
  IsEmpty
  (
        Filter
        (
          [Measures].[Actual  Hours]
         ,
          [WORK ACTUAL].[MAINT D].[Maintenance Code] = 'PRO'
        )
      / 
        [Measures].[Actual  Hours]
    * 100
  )
 ,0
 ,
      Filter
      (
        [Measures].[Actual  Hours]
       ,
        [WORK ORDER ACTUAL].[MAINT D].[Maintenance Code] = 'PRO'
      )
    / 
      [Measures].[Actual  Hours]
  * 100
)
```

I got the following error :

> MdxScript(test)the divide function expects a string or numeric
>   expression for the 1 argument. A tuple set expression was used .

Comment: I'd like to help but rather than guessing could you please tell me the  desired result of this calculation - can you explain in words please? Also the context - is this part of a bigger script, or does this logic go into another tool e.g. ssrs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Filter function returns a *set* hence your error message:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146037.aspx

> Returns the set that results from filtering a specified set based on a search condition.

So you are trying to divide a *set* of members by a number.

To resolve it you need a numeric expression instead of a set. Numeric expressions are either of the following:

1. A number
2. A numeric measure
3. A numeric formatted member property
4. The result of a tuple

Probably number 4 is the trickiest concept in `mdx` for someone new to the language to understand.

As @BillAnton has mentioned this is a tuple and hence a numeric expression:

```
([WORK ACTUAL].[MAINT D].&[PRO],[Measures].[Actual  Hours])
```

This is also a tuple and numeric expression:

```
([WORK ACTUAL].[MAINT D].&[PRO])
```

It will simply use the measure that is used in the context of the script or the cubes default measure.

Also in the definition of `Filter` you can see that it's signature is as follows:

> Filter(Set_Expression, Logical_Expression )

In your script you have the following

```
Filter
    (
      [Measures].[Actual  Hours] //<<measures are numeric_expression
     ,
      [WORK ACTUAL].[MAINT D].[Maintenance Code] = 'PRO'
    )
```

In terms of getting rid of the error here is 1 resolution:

```
IIF
(
      //10 is a numeric placeholder (you can replace with something that returns a number)
      10 / [Measures].[Actual  Hours]
    * 100
  = 0
 ,0
 ,
    //20 is a numeric placeholder (you can replace with something that returns a number)
    20 / [Measures].[Actual  Hours]
  * 100
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the Filter function correctly. Filter-function is typically used to filter a set of tuples by a measure or some other calculated logic. In order to filter a measure by a specific member (which is what I think you're trying to do), you can simply create a tuple...

```
([WORK ACTUAL].[MAINT D].&[PRO],[Measures].[Actual  Hours])
```

This calculates actual hours (using the defined aggregation function which is most likely SUM) using fact records associated to the [PRO] member of the [Maint D] attribute in the [Work Actual] dimension. Depending on how your dimension/attribute/etc is setup, this may not be the precise syntax...but hopefully you get the idea.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[<calc-measure-stage1>]
    IIF(
        [Measures].[Actual  Hours] = 0
        ,NULL
        ,(
            (
                 [WORK ACTUAL].[MAINT D].&[PRO]
                ,[Measures].[Actual  Hours]
            )
            /
            [Measures].[Actual  Hours]
         ) * 100
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[<calc-measure-stage2>]
    IIF(
        [Measures].[Actual  Hours] = 0
        ,NULL
        ,(
            (
                 [WORK ORDER ACTUAL].[MAINT D].&[PRO]
                ,[Measures].[Actual  Hours]
            )
            /
            [Measures].[Actual  Hours]
         ) * 100
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[<calc-measure>]
    IIF(
         IsEmpty([Measures].[<calc-measure-stage1>]
        ,[Measures].[<calc-measure-stage2>]
        ,[Measures].[<calc-measure-stage1>]
    )
```

Comment: upped this answer Bill - although it is tricky to interpret the question and know exactly what the user would like from this calc..

Comment: when the calc includes `[Measures].[Actual  Hours]` in the tuple and then divides by `[Measures].[Actual  Hours]` is the answer not just 1?

Comment: no...because the dividend is a subset of the divisor. It's similar to a percent of parent calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Use CoalesceEmpty(Expression, NumaricValue) for numeric measures

Also use DIVIDE(Numerator, Denominator, 0) which automatically handles devided by 0 exception